# Java Swing JButton getResource not working well

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, getresource

This code runs correctly on windows XP. But at home on my Windows 7 machine I can't see the icons because getResource returns null. I've tried an absolute path and it's not working either. I don't know what to do, I'm running Eclipse in Admin mode:

```
private static JButton createToolButton(String imgName, String altText, String toolTipText) {

    String imagePath = IMG_URL + "/" + imgName;

    URL imageUrl = SwingUtility.class.getResource(imagePath);
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setToolTipText(toolTipText);

    if(imageUrl != null) //Image trouvé
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageUrl, altText));
    else
        button.setText(altText);

    return button;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of IMG_URL?

Comment: `IMG_URL="../../images";`, the class is in a src folder two level's lower, so I go up two level's into the images folder that contain's a bunch of pictures. I know this path works, I mean if it worked on two windows XP machine's, surely the problem is elsewhere?

Comment: can't know, but it's always the path ;-) If it works on one machine and not on another then there's a slight difference in the setup - try to find it

Answer (score 1):

The `getResource()` method will first search the parent class loader for the resource; if the parent is null the path of the class loader built-in to the virtual machine is searched. That failing, this method will invoke `findResource(String)` to find the resource. So after all these, if it returns null, the problem is with `imagepath` ergo `IMG_URL`. Also note that it returns null if the resource could not be found or **the invoker doesn't have adequate privileges to get the resource.**

Comment: I did think about privilege's, that's why I ran eclispe as an administrator, I'm not sure if I can change the permissions of my images folder(Miss my chmod...), I'll check it out.

Comment: @Pat thats why I mentioned it in bold :)

Comment: I know it's silly of mine, but have you tried using `/path/to/ + imgName` instead of `../../`?

Comment: This doesn't work either :`URL imageUrl = SwingUtility.class.getResource("C:/Users/Pat/Documents/LOG-110/TravailPratique4/images/up.gif");` my permissions are fine

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, not ideal but it works. After many tests I just feel like using the dot notation to go up and into the current directory not work exactly as expected using the basic java utilities. Ended up just getting the project path and splitting it where I wanted, hasn't been tested on other machines yet.

```
private static JButton createToolButton(String imgName, String altText, String toolTipText) 
{
    String imagePath = IMG_FOLDER_NAME + "\\" + imgName;
    BufferedImage img = null;
    JButton button = new JButton();

    try 
    {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(projectPath() + imagePath));
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    button.setToolTipText(toolTipText);

    if(img != null)
       button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img, altText));
    else
       button.setText(altText);

    return button;
}

private static String projectPath()
{
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL url = classLoader.getResource("");
    String pathArr[] = url.getPath().split(PATH_SEPARATOR);
    return pathArr[0];
}
```